# Selenium IDE: read set of data from excel

Tags: excel, selenium, parameters, ide

This is actually not a question but solution proposal: I found workaround to read set of data from excel. in this case there is no need for multiple users or data variation but read parameters to create a validation environment.

ok, solution is to save excel file to html format and then let the Selenium IDE to read parameters from that. Users needs only to agree the same filename to be used.

Answer (score 1):

```
1) you should add "Apache POI" jar files in order to read your excel through java.


import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelReadExample {

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {



        String filename = "E:\\data.xls";



        List sheetData = new ArrayList();

        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {

            fis = new FileInputStream(filename);

            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();
            while (rows.hasNext()) {
                XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow) rows.next();
                Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();

                List data = new ArrayList();
                while (cells.hasNext()) {
                    XSSFCell cell = (XSSFCell) cells.next();
                    data.add(cell);
                }

                sheetData.add(data);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fis != null) {
                fis.close();
            }
        }

        showExelData(sheetData);
    }

    private static void showExelData(List sheetData) {


        int sum = 0;




        for (int i = 0; i < sheetData.size(); i++) {
            List<XSSFCell> list = (List) sheetData.get(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
                XSSFCell cell = (XSSFCell) list.get(j);


                if(cell.getCellType()==0)
                {
                    sum += cell.getNumericCellValue();

                }

            }
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Sum Value is:" +sum);
        }
    }
}



Change the file path.
i hve mentioned my sheet name as "input" change it as per yours
Happy excelling :D
```